# Infinite loop when c++ bool function returns true

Tags: c++, boolean, infinite-loop

i am writing code for a college c++ assignment. the program is supposed to print the first 5 primes of the fibonacci sequence. heres what i have so far.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
int fibonacci(int x){
 int y=1, z=1, sum=0;
  for(int a=1; a<=x;a++){
    sum=(z+y);
z=y;
y=sum;
  }
  return sum;
}
bool isPrime(int x){
  double z=x;
  for(int y=2;y<=sqrt(z);y++){
    if(x%y==0){
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
int main(){
  int primes=0, check=0;
  for(int x=1;x<=10;x++){
    check=0;
    while(primes<5 && check==0){
      if(isPrime(fibonacci(x))){
       cout<<fibonacci(x)<<endl;
       primes++;
       check=1;
      }
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

the code returns the first 3 fibonacci primes, 2, 3 and 5. the program then enters an infinite loop. ensuring that the isPrime function returns true eliminates the infinite loop, but obviously does not produce the needed output. 
any help would be greatly appreciated. thanks.

Comment: Well, if `isPrime` is `false` your loop in `main` doesn't do anything. It's not clear to me what else you expected to happen.

Comment: I guess they won't accept `cout << "2 3 5 13 89";`? :)

Comment: SO is not the place to ask for simple debugging mistakes to be fixed. every time you ask a question it should be something other readers in the future should be able to profit from themselves. i would suggest you google for general methods on how do debug your code, like using debug mode and setting breakpoints to fix your issue

Comment: Check your main loops (if a fibonacci number is not a prime then you are just stuck in the while loop because check will always be 0). But there is no need for a `for` loop. Just use the `while` loop which should break after 5 primes have been found. Learn how to debug and these kinds of problems will become easy to fix.

Comment: BTW, you don't need to check even numbers after 2 for prime.  After 2, all primes are odd numbers.  Increment by 2.

Comment: thank you philipp. i moved the line to change check out of the if statement, and the program works as expected.

Comment: neuron, will do. apologies. im a first semester student and im still new to the system and online community. do you have any specific resources you could point me to?

Answer (score 1):

Your functions to find the Fibonacci and check if it was prime were fine. They could have been modified a bit more for efficiency but they looked ok. The problem was with the things running inside your `main`. You made too many unnecessary variables and comparisons in there. 
I worked on the code and it seems to be working now. Keep in mind I am in my class so there might be some errors haha.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
int fibonacci(int x) {
    int y = 1, z = 1, sum = 0;
    for (int a = 1; a <= x; a++) {
        sum = (z + y);
        z = y;
        y = sum;
    }
    return sum;
}
bool isPrime(int x) {
    double z = x;
    for (int y = 2; y <= sqrt(z); y++) {

        if (x%y == 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
int main() {
    int primes = 0, check = 0;
    for (int x = 1; primes < 5; x++) {

        if (isPrime(fibonacci(x)))
        {
            cout << fibonacci(x) << endl;
            primes++;
        }
    }
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

I believe your `check` was placed in the improper position and was causing the infinite loop.